# Implementation of mid point summation Python

Tags: python, montecarlo

I'm trying to implement a code in python in order to resolve D integral, for D=1,2,3..,8,  with the Monte Carlo method called Midpoint summation:

[image]

I wrote this code:

```
import numpy as np                       #library for numerical calculations
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt          #library for plotting purposes
from scipy import random                 #needed for generate random number
from sympy import symbols, integrate     #needed for integrate function
from scipy.stats import norm             #needed for gaussian fit
from time import process_time            #function needed for checking CPU time

#*******************************************************************************

def f(x,D):                              #definition of the function to integrate
  return D*(x**2)

#*******************************************************************************

a=0                                     #extreme of integration

b=1                                     #extreme of integration

N = 10**7                               #number of point generated, statistics

for d in range(1,9):                    #for cycle over all the integral
  
  t1_start = process_time()                   #process start time  
  
  dx = (b-a)/N                                #just a variable
  
  x_midpoint = np.linspace(dx/2,b - dx/2,N)   #midpoint x

  midpoint = np.sum(f(x_midpoint,d) * dx)     #result of the integral d
  
  t1_stop = process_time()                    #process stop time     
  
  print("The CPU time needed for getting the integral is:", t1_stop-t1_start, "seconds.\n")
  print("The result of integral with dimension D =", d, "is:", midpoint, ".\n")

#*******************************************************************************
```

The result given by the output are correct:

```
The CPU time needed for getting the integral is: 0.092512959999965 seconds.

The result of integral with dimension D = 1 is: 0.33333333333333254 .

The CPU time needed for getting the integral is: 0.08751376800000799 seconds.

The result of integral with dimension D = 2 is: 0.6666666666666651 .

The CPU time needed for getting the integral is: 0.08883859700000585 seconds.

The result of integral with dimension D = 3 is: 0.9999999999999968 .

The CPU time needed for getting the integral is: 0.08805979900000693 seconds.

The result of integral with dimension D = 4 is: 1.3333333333333302 .

The CPU time needed for getting the integral is: 0.08753954700000577 seconds.

The result of integral with dimension D = 5 is: 1.6666666666666625 .

The CPU time needed for getting the integral is: 0.11455608900001835 seconds.

The result of integral with dimension D = 6 is: 1.9999999999999936 .

The CPU time needed for getting the integral is: 0.11915848600000345 seconds.

The result of integral with dimension D = 7 is: 2.333333333333328 .

The CPU time needed for getting the integral is: 0.11481723499997543 seconds.

The result of integral with dimension D = 8 is: 2.6666666666666603 .
```

but in my opinion i think that the method implemented in my code is different from the Monte Carlo method of midpoint summation.

How can i implement it in the right way?

Comment: what is N in above formula ?

Comment: any link to the formula ?

Comment: N is the number of point generated for the Monte Carlo method.